# GnuCOBOL not generating dynamic link library ELF references

Tags: compiling, gcc, ld, dynamic-linking

Now GnuCOBOL, the Ubuntu package is open-cobol.

As of Ubuntu 14.04? the compiler fails to link in dynamic library references for dlopen to use at run-time.  No trace of the library in `ldd` from gcc `-l` link library hints.

This has worked for a long time, and something seems to have changed in `ld` invocation or assumptions?

Technical details at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227458/gnucobol-failing-to-find-dynamic-symbols-only-on-recent-ubuntu

The same cobc sources, built on Fedora, generates binaries where `ldd` has the dynamic link library entries.  The CALL feature has been working since 2006 ish.

If anyone knows of a recent change to dlopen?, dlsym?, autotools? linker optimizations? (GnuCOBOL CALL is dynamic, effectively by string name at run-time, and not passed through ld linkage), or ld.so.conf?

gcc switch assumption? ldconfig defaults?

GnuCOBOL is hobbled, and it would be great if someone can point to what might need to be done to get `-l` libraries back in ELF binaries.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Path to fix posted to the StackOverflow question linked above.

`export COB_LDFLAGS='-Wl,--no-as-needed'` is the easy fix to get around this change to linker optimization.  The real fix will be a little deeper, but Petesh offered the hint that fills the immediate need.